# How to save decoded image in server using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, server, base64, image-uploading

I have written this code for saving decoded `images` locally and it works fine. Actually I need to save this decoded `image` in a server, but I don't now how to achieve this? I have seen many examples saving files in server, but here I have a `base64 decoded image` ... Can I get any hint ? Thanks in advance

```
Dim bt64 As Byte() = System.Convert.FromBase64String(srcFile)

Dim destFile As String = " C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\MASavedImages"

Dim imgName As String

imgName = String.Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy hh-mm-ss tt-fff}", DateTime.Now)

imgName += ".jpg"

If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(destFile)) Then

    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(destFile)

    File.WriteAllBytes(destFile + "\" + imgName, decodedimg)

Else

    File.WriteAllBytes(destFile + "\" + imgName, decodedimg)

End If
```

Comment: _What kind of server??_ You must be specific when you ask a question! There are MANY different kinds of servers: Web server (for a website), FTP server, a normal computer functioning as a server, dedicated server, servers accessible only via their own interface (like DropBox), Samba servers, _and so on and so forth_.

Answer (score 0):

And why can't you save to server by the same method ? What happens when you change the destFile to \\server\path\filename and run ?